# Should I use ThreadStart to create a thread? can't find a vb.net example

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, multithreading

Is it common to create threads using `ThreadStart`?

I cannot find a vb.net example of how to do it.

Comment: [Converters](http://converter.telerik.com/) should do it. But if you're in .Net 4.0 or above don't use threads, just use TPL.

Comment: The [`MSDN Documentation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a9fyxz7d(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: I'm afraid to use automatic converters. Too risky...

Comment: @ilanS Not at all. They do their job well. At least telerik is good.

Comment: You don't. Create and run a [task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need the ThreadStart, just do:

```
Dim t As New Thread(Sub() RealStart(param1, param2))
t.Start()
```

Comment: Not sure why they set it up that way.  See [ThreadStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): "Visual Basic and C# users can omit the ThreadStart or ParameterizedThreadStart delegate constructor when creating a thread."